# REST API design for reordering items with pagination

Tags: c#, .net, rest, pagination

Here's the scenario, simplified, I have a list of colors items, and "Folders" in which colors can be put.
But it also needs to have a pagination, and changeable order, like moving items within a folder up or down, with an up/down arrow.

So I have 3 SQL db tables:

```
Folder
--FolderId
--Name
--Deleted (bool)

Color
--ColorId
--Name
--Deleted (bool)

ColorFolder
--ColorFolderId
--ColorId
--FolderId
--Deleted (bool)
```

For example, I add an int field Position, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...
How should I approach customizable order API?

Initial idea was to just switch places of the two items, +1 on one item, -1 on the other. But what if I delete one item in the middle:

```
Example:
Name    Position
Blue    1
Red     2
Pink    3
Yellow  4
Orange  5
```

If I remove Yellow (Deleted = 1), and want to move Pink up, above Red, +/-1 won't do the desired effect.

```
Example:
Name    Position
Blue    1
Red     2 (+ 1 = 3)
Pink    4 (- 1 = 3) 
Orange  5
```

Second idea was to send a map of all IDs and their position via PUT, but that is a problem since the list has pagination, so on frontend I don't have all the IDs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As of the REST part, you design a webservice, not data storage. So I would approach this from service perspective or in other terms what is that your webservice consumers need?

Changes are usually problematic if there can be parallel requests, but you can do versioning with [if-unmodified-since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Unmodified-Since) or [if-match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Match), so it is possible to just PATCH a collection resource with [JSONPatch](https://jsonpatch.com/) in the request body instead of sending the whole thing with PUT. Though as far as I can tell JSONPatch does not allow this kind of reordering, at least it does countless replaces instead of simple moving. So maybe better to stick to a custom approach.

As of the actual algorithm, maybe this answers that part of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24662904/607033

Moving items with arrows is a little bit outdated nowadays. Usually we do it with drag & drop with something like `move(oldIndex, newIndex)` or you can choose identifiers and not care about the indexes at all in the API. For paginated collections I am not sure. I mean the upper works and we are talking about webservice consumer applications not user interfaces, so for those it does not matter. For users, you just need to load another page and continue moving the item. Switching places with a REST API would mean `n = abs(oldIndex-newIndex)` HTTP requests, so it is definitely not a good solution.

So I think this is rather a how to design a GUI for this instead of a REST question. From GUI perspective I would have some sort of selection or container which holds the selected item. And I would paginate and drag it from the container and drop it to the right place if I would insist to paginate with arrows or page numbers instead of using seamless pagination.

For example a custom solution similar to JSONPatch is something like this:

```
PATCH /items {"op": "reposition", "subject": {id:4}, "targetPosition": {id:2}}
PATCH /items {"op": "rearrange", "subject": {id:4}, "toIndex": 1}
PATCH /items {"op": "rearrange", "fromIndex": 7, "toIndex": 1}
```

If you want to move multiple items at once, then better to send the whole collection or at least the pages where you changed the order and calculate the difference server side.